# In the Azure portal where do I turn on DDoS IP protection for an azure app service? eg an API

Tags: azure, azure-vpn, azure-ddos

I can't see in the portal where to enable this for my azure app service? I can see at the vnet level the option is there... but that will give me "Azure DDoS Network Protection" which is thousands of dollars per month.

I just want to enable for the IP address of the Azure App Service (the rest api)

Comment: Have you looked at Azure Application Gateway? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/tutorial-protect-application-gateway-ddos

Comment: no I haven't... I'm guessing I need to in order to DDOS protect the Azure App Service?

Comment: yeh not sure I need application gateway

Comment: Could you elaborate your question, Do you need to enable DDOS protection or not ?

Comment: yes I need DDOS protection but the ip based one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure App Service does not offer this capability natively. You need to use [another service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ddos-protection/ddos-protection-reference-architectures#paas-web-application) (App Gateway, Load Balancer with public IP, Front door) that supports DDOS and put it in front of your App Service.